# Xcode 6: iOS Swift. How to get in game frame rate (fps)?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, frame-rate

In my current Swift project for iOS, I need to divide a variable by current FPS on the device I am running it on. In my case, the program is running on my iPad mini. I don't see a function, or any capability to do this. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

There is however, in "GameViewController.swift" a line:

```
skView.showsFPS = true
```

But I cannot access this value.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I never used iOS before, but on android I used something like this on the onDraw function:

```
dt = currentTime - lastTime;
lastTime = currentTime;         
tempDt += dt;
fps += 1;
if (tempDt >= 1000) {
    Log.d("FPS", String.format("%d", fps));
    tempDt = 0;
    fps = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the SKView `frameInterval` property in the `didMoveToView:(SKView *)view` method.

If the value is 1 you are running a 60 FPS. If the value is 2 you are running at 30 FPS. Anything else, get out your calculator.

You can read up more detail in the Apple SKView [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKView/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKView/frameInterval).

You set the FPS in the GameViewController:

```
skView.frameInterval = 2;
```

Convert an integer to a float:

```
int myInt = 10;
float myFloat = (float)myInt;
```

Comment: That helps, but I need to either be able to set the frame rate, or read it. The frameInterval only counts the number of frames until it needs to update, which is also an integer, not a float or double